# sensible SQL timeouts

Tags: c#, sql

When you execute a query against a database, what is a sensible timeout strategy.  Normally I just leave the default in place, but wondered if there was a sensible rule of thumb?  What would a DBA typically like to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those *"it depends"* answers.  There are a lot of expensive queries on millions of rows of data that timeout with the default setting.

What a strategy I use is to set that to `0` (in other words, **no timeout**), and then use SQL Profiler (run a trace) to get the duration.  I multiple that times `1.15` to give myself a 15% buffer so that I don't timeout due to system latency or just a "slow" execution.  But in my opinion, if 115% of the time has passed when tested and it is not completed, 9 times out of 10 something went wrong and a timeout is in order.

Comment: cool.  You set a fairly tight limit then.  That's kind of the direction I was thinking in.  Does it take much effort to maintain durations?  Maybe if a duration threshold is reached, it's an indicator that performance tuning is needed.  What's your take on that?

Comment: It doesn't take much effort at all. And you can loosen the buffer up to 25%today if you like (or more) if your server has sporadic performance. And I agree that if the timeouts are happening frequently, as long as there isn't an error holding it up, that's a very straightforward sign that performance has degraded and needs attention/tuning.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is really dependent on what you are doing. If we are talking about reporting, then you'll probably need a much higher timeout than if you are doing simple selects/inserts/deletes.

We normally only allow 30s on non-reporting queries and 3m on our reporting server.

Comment: would you throw these values in a config file or hard code them?

Comment: Hard-coding is bad. Pretty much ever.

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting to SQL Server using the SqlCommand and SqlConnection classes, then there are two timeouts you need to think about:

SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout

The time needed to get a connection to the database, this defaults to 30 seconds which in my opinion is much too long. We reduce that to 5 seconds.

And

SqlCommand.CommandTimeout

Which obviously depends on the query you are running.